# advantage ole db provider 10.0.0.3 adsoledb for 64 bit - can't get it to work

Tags: advantage-database-server

trying to get a local server version of Advantage OLE DB Provider to work on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine. installed the 64 bit version 10.00.0.3 release and copied my application. registered the adsoledb64.dll from the app directory. I get nothing. Doesn't write a log either. Am I going to have to compile the app on the 64 bit machine? very confused and frustrated.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on "get nothing"?  Is there an error?  Does your application successfully load the provider?  Is there an error connecting? Or does it connect and then not get data?

Comment: I do not get anything written to ads_err.dbf and no err from my .net app. I did test the app on a 32 bit machine (compiled AnyCPU) Works fine there. 
The advantage oledb provider comes in a 32 bit install and a 64 bit install (which will only install on 64 bit machine).
My app iself was compiled on a 32bit workstation and copied (with its numerous dlls) onto the 64 bit machine I have for testing.
Wondering if I need to register more dlls or dlls in the wrong place..would love advice if anyone has this working. Perhaps I need some try catch written into the app for the connection.

Comment: Also for the compile I want to run on the 64bit I have the advantage connected library compiled as x64 but some of the other libraries in the app will only compile for AnyCPU or x86 so its a bit of a mix...there are 6 libs altogether.

Comment: It would help if you can isolate where the failure occurs in order to help us know what to suggest.  It is not clear to me if you are successfully connecting.  Do you have some try/catch blocks that are gobbling up exceptions perhaps?  I assume you are using OleDbConnection objects; is that true?

Comment: Yep using OleDbConnection objects. I did have a catch in there for the connection..when I take it out my app does crash with the Windows 7 will look for the problem kind of error :) but no err file written still. I don't think the provider string is any diff for x64. Not sure if there are returns I can check...I have checked devzone but not tons of examples there.

It works so well on my 32 bit machine I had not tinkered with it much. 
Wondering if I should try and install visual studio on the 64 bit machine (if I can get permission) to see if that will give me a clue?

Comment: If the connect attempt produces an exception, then it probably means the provider cannot be loaded (and if it can't be loaded, it would never get to the point of being able to log errors).  The exception should give you some more information on what the problem is.  It could be that your application is being forced to run as a 32-bit application.  If so, then you will need to install the 32-bit version of the data provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information I have gleaned from the comments, it sounds as if your application is running as a 32-bit application.  If so, it will not be able to load 64-bit version of the OLE DB provider.  The `conn.Open();` call would likely result in an error such as this:

```
The 'Advantage.OLEDB.1' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

One way to test this would be to install the 32-bit version of the provider to see if it works.

Alternatively, you might consider using the [Advantage .NET Data Provider](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=15&Product=4&Platform=11) rather than the OLE DB provider. Using a native data provider instead of going through OLE DB might prove simpler in the long run.

Comment: Indeed ended up with the app and lib with adv running as x86 and it worked. It did think that because I was on a virtual machine I was doing server so it threw an error for that (5185). You can put setting in ads.ini to get around that. Yes I think pure 64 apps are still rare...so runs as 32 on 64 machine is ok for me for now. I did switch to the .net provider as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @thomcat: I'm glad you got it working.  Thanks for reporting back with your findings.